Are pairs of triple 2x12 beams adequate for a vehicle bridge spanning 10 feet?
I need to build a bridge over a creek for my farm tractor. I need to know how much weight can a triple 2x12 glued and screwed beam support over a 10' span. My tractor weighs 6,000lbs. I was thinking of 2 beams 12" apart under each wheel and then another beam in the center. It will be supported by concrete blocks on each end.
2x6 decking with possibly 2x12 on top of that as "tracks" for the tires to distribute a bit more load.

Adhesives applied in the field are never considered structural (especially outdoors). Also, you'd use bolts for something like this, not screws.

Are you suggesting two triple beams under each track and a fifth one in the center? That's undoubtedly adequate.

Yes, I am planning on 2 triple beams under each wheel and a 5th beam running down the center. Is the 5th necessary?

Depends on your choice of decking. You haven't told us that. It would need to carry a narrow-front tractor itself, for example.

I strongly suggest poured concrete rather than block. Block depends on a very stable footing and top bracing situation or it's at risk of collapse.

I was thinking of 2x6 decking and possibly 2x12 on top of that as "tracks" for the tires to distribute load. The front wheels are the same width as the rears and not narrow.

It's not just about you/now. It's about what you or others might do later. :)

FYI, I'm not posting an answer because I don't generally respond to load calculation questions--tools abound on the internet that you can use as easily as I can. Also, I'm not sure this question is on topic here. Bridge construction isn't really home improvement per the [help].

I wouldn't do the "tracks" thing because while you are using this tractor now, the next one might have different tire positions, or someone will need to move other equipment. Build it strong and with some wood on each edge as a guard from accidentally rolling off the side.

valid point isherwood. I have searched a great deal, but I cannot find a definitive answer to triple 2x12 weight capacity with support only on the ends at a 10' span. If it's 1500# at center then 4 beams will be more than sufficient especially since when the front is in the center, about half the weight is on the center and the same when the rears are on the center. But again, I cannot find an "answer."

manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact, this is on my land with no other tractors, but UTVs.
I have no intention of changing tractors since it's brand new and it will outlast the wood.

I have left a few cement blocks on the ground.  After ~10 years quite a few of them were almost powder, freeze/thaw cycles.

If the decking cannot support the weight of the tractor except directly over the beams, I don't see the point of the tracks except to guide the driver to the correct tracking.  They don't need thickness,you could use paint.  Or guide rails at the entrance like at a drive-through car wash.   You say "distribute the load" but you can't have the tracks distributing the load lengthwise across the beams.  The beams have to do that inherently, otherwise you're building a truss bridge ... which is definitely out of scope here.

why a bridge instead of a culvert?

We originally started thinking about a culvert. It's not a stream we are going over but more like water run-off. It's 6' deep and 4' wide of the bottom and 10' wide at the top. Gravel is quite a bit of $$$ for that amount. And the "fill dirt" around us is sandy clay. It can be problematic compacting firm enough and we'd have to build a retaining wall on each side to hold it back from washing away.

@Jasen a bridge will nearly always have a higher hydraulic capacity than a culvert, unless it's a box culvert.
